# format with a for loop getting ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm using the following code:

```
string="Verificamos {} vem crescendo em media {} porcento ao ano. A empresa {} por exemplo {}"
df['go']=[string.format(*r) for r in dfcres[['CNAE_x','Crescimento_t11_Peers_CNAE','Top_Cres1','Top_Cres1%']].values.tolist()]
```

If I print `dfcres[['CNAE_x','Crescimento_t11_Peers_CNAE','Top_Cres1','Top_Cres1%']]`, I get:

```
         CNAE_x     Crescimento_t11_Peers_CNAE    Top_Cres1   Top_Cres1%
6     "bovinos"                           0.10  "Maria Ltd"         0.22
8      "suínos"                           0.08  "Carla Ltd"         0.10
9  "construção"                           0.93    "Mark SA"         0.30
```

So, df['go'] should look like this:

```
  go
6 "Verificamos bovinos vem crescendo em media 0.10 porcento ao ano. A empresa Maria Ltd por exemplo 0.22"
8 "Verificamos suínos vem crescendo em media 0.08 porcento ao ano. A empresa Carla Ltd por exemplo 0.10"
9 "Verificamos construção vem crescendo em media 0.93 porcento ao ano. A empresa Maria Ltda por exemplo 0.30"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I have no idea what does this error mean. Could someone help or suggest another way to get the same result?

Comment: You're trying to write to `df`, but you're pulling values from `dfcres`.  Write to `dfcres['go']` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your python version? It works for me using this example on Python 3.6.4:

```
      CNAE_x  Outravar1   Crescimento_t11_Peers_CNAE    Top_Cres1   Top_Cres1% Outravar2
   "bovinos"         12                         0.10  "Maria Ltd"         0.22    "vaca"
    "suínos"       1575                         0.08  "Carla Ltd"         0.10   "porco"
"construção"        358                         0.93    "Mark SA"         0.30   "casas"
```

And coding:

```
>>> dfcres = pd.read_clipboard()
    dfcres
    CNAE_x  Outravar1   Crescimento_t11_Peers_CNAE  Top_Cres1   Top_Cres1%  Outravar2
0   bovinos       12                        0.10    Maria Ltd   0.22     vaca
1   suínos      1575                        0.08    Carla Ltd   0.10    porco
2   construção   358                        0.93    Mark SA     0.30    casas
```

But if `df` hasn't the same number of rows that `dfcresc`, eg.

```
>>> df
    CNAE_x  Outravar1   Crescimento_t11_Peers_CNAE  Top_Cres1   Top_Cres1%  Outravar2
0   bovinos       12                        0.10    Maria Ltd   0.22     vaca
1   construção   358                        0.93    Mark SA     0.30    casas
```

Then you'll still getting this message error.

You should avoid this method if you're not sure if both dataframes have the same number of rows.

If my guess is correct, `df` is a dataframe of brazilian economic activities (CNAE). So, you could use `CNAE_x` as unique identifier, for example:

First, create the column **dfcres['go']**:

```
dfcres['go']=[string.format(*r) for r in dfcres.loc[,'CNAE_x','Crescimento_t11_Peers_CNAE','Top_Cres1','Top_Cres1%']].values.tolist()]
```

Then join data matching rows with same `CNAE_x` value:

```
pd.merge(df, dfcres,
    how='right', on='CNAE_x')
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on my own computer without having `dfcres`, and just kept the values as a list. This worked. So, I suspect the problem lies in either:

1. You are probable missing `{}` in front. (Your expected results start with a number), or
2. the two brackets instead of one, or
3. How many values the `values()` function returns

Try to go from there